# Paperclip error [paperclip] Content Type Spoof in nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, nginx, paperclip

I run my rails application locally and everything is perfect. But running in a nginx server I get this error:

`User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  users.* FROM users WHERE users.id = 15482 ORDER BY users.id ASC LIMIT 1
App 12917 stderr:   Artist Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  users.* FROM users WHERE users.type IN ('Artist') AND users.id = 15482 LIMIT 1
App 12917 stderr:    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
App 12917 stderr: Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/c705bd2b503af7c522d45bc0f1bb849720170623-12978-t8220f.jpeg'
App 12917 stderr: [paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename boxImg22.jpeg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
App 12917 stderr:   User Exists (4.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM users WHERE users.email = BINARY 'manfe@gmail.com' AND (users.id != 15482) LIMIT 1
App 12917 stderr:    (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK`

It does not me allow to upload any file with paperclip ( images and pdf ).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I resolved. I uninstall ImageMagick. ( it was installed with wget, tar, make and so on ). And installed with **apt-get install imagemagick**